# jquery/js if statement

Tags: jquery, if-statement

Is it possible with jquery to hide or show a section of code (not run it) like one would do with php.

```
<?php if( $searchDone <> 0 ){ ?>
<script type="text/javascript">$().ready(function() {
$('.radiocontainer input:radio[name=search_Inclusive]').bind('change', function(){ submitSearch() });
});</script>
<?php } ?>
```

I dont want to run any code if the statement is true, I just want it "available for use". Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: If you'd like to offer more detail on what functionality or end result you're going for than a better solution can probably be found. What you're doing with that code snippet is making me cringe.

Answer (score 0):

With JavaScript, you can simply wrap it like so:

```
myfunc();
```

becomes:

```
if (0) { myfunc(); }  // (will not run)
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP runs on the server, not on the client, so you'd have to have PHP spit out bit of javascript to set a variable flag, or just not output the javascript code chunk question.

setting a flag:

```
<script>
   var run_the_code = <?php echo ($searchDone <> 0) ? '1' : '0' ?>;
   if (run_the_code) {
      $('.....etc....');
   }
</script>
```

omitting the call:

```
<?php if ($searchDone != 0) { ?>
<script ...>
   // will not appear in the generated page if $searchDone is 0
   $('.radiocontainer ....').....;
</script>
<?php } ?>
```